# How to evaluate http response of the a valid site url?

Tags: api, http, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I use a logic App and I need to evaluate the status of a specific site.

e.g. I want to create a site with the name: https://[Tentant].sharepoint.com/sites/test01
then I use the following http request:
_api/GroupSiteManager/GetValidSiteUrlFromAlias?alias='test01'&isTeamSite=true

When this is correct I can create the site, otherwise if terminate the workflow.

My question is how I can check if the reponse is ok or true?

[image: My Logic App]

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: What response did you get?

Comment: If you get a useful respons, you can use a condition control to validate the result.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from end I could able to achieve your requirement by using `outputs('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['statusCode']` to check if the step is successful in a condition and redirect the steps further accordingly. Below is the flow in my logic apps.

[image]

*RESULTS:*

[image]

**Note:** If the condition fails the logic app gets terminated.